# Map over an object array and display another element at a certain position

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, gatsby

I am not sure if my title is clear.

I am working on a blog and I am currently displaying a list of posts on the homepage.
Visualy i use a flexbox with rows of 3 articles.

To do that I simply map over an array of posts that are objects with all the information on the post.
Know I wish to add a Newsletter bloc next to the second post replacing the third post, and third post would simply wrap and go to the next line.

My code currently is:

```
<section className="post-feed">
   {currentList.slice(1).map(({ node }) => (
     // The tag below includes the markup for each post 
        components/common/PostCard.js
     // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-key
        <PostCard key={node.id} post={node} />
    ))}
</section>
```

I am not sure how I could insert another component into this list.

Comment: You mean inside `.map()` method you need to return one more component along with `<PostCard />` ?

Comment: Yes I need to add a <Newsletter /> component at 3rd position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the map key to know when he map is in the 3rd position:

```
<section className="post-feed">
   {currentList.slice(1).map(({ node }, key) => (
        <>
            { key === 2 && <NewsletterComponent />}
            <PostCard key={node.id} post={node} />
        </>
    ))}
</section>
```

Comment: Yeah exactly this is working ! I tried it adding an `i` instead `key` and it didn't work, but I forgot to use `&&` instead was using `{ i === 2 ? <NewsletterComponent /> : null }` ! Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would go with this approach:

Write an if-statement inside your map-function that checks if the current item the map-function loops over is the last/third (I assume last = third). If that's the case render/return the newsletter component/block.

Give it a try and let me know if it fits.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I have taken the previous solution as I tried something similar but have no clue why it didn't work ! I probably missed something stupid!